# Opening netCDF and creating raster file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, netcdf

I want to open a netCDF file and create a raster with ArcMap 10.2. The file contains the mean monthly temperature for Switzerland. I found it in meteoswiss web site.

I tried to open it with the multidimension tool and make a netCDF raster layer but when I select the file to open automatically gis put the info in X dimension and Y dimension but I have the error 000237 (One or more dimensions are invalid). Even if I change the variable for the x and y dimensions I have still the same error.

I tried also to drop the file directly into ArcMap and in that case I have just a point (and a message saying that there is no coordinate system so I added the coordinate system, WGS 1984, but nothing changes).

I found this question that I found helpful:  [Importing NetCDF file to ArcGIS Desktop as point feature layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84996/issues-with-importing-a-netcdf-file-to-arcgis-as-a-point-feature-layer) 
but my problem is that I can't create the file with the coordinate.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArcGIS 10.3.1 you can just drag and drop.  I downloaded a SST raster from NOAA and dragged it into a dataframe that was pre-set to WGS84. Worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

There are likely many ways to solve this, but now that ESRI provides the [Multidimensional Supplemental Tools](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9f963f362fe5417f87d44618796db938) that includes the NetCDF4-Python library, one way is to load subsets of local NetCDF files or remote OPeNDAP datasets into raster using scripts like this:

https://github.com/rsignell-usgs/dap2arc/blob/master/src/dap2raster.py